# Access a managed bean from cxf web service

Tags: web-services, jsf-2, cxf

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "login")
public class LoginService{
 loginCredentials.login();
 }
```

public class LoginCredentials {

```
@ManagedProperty(name = "applicationBD", value = "#{applicationBD}")
private IApplication applicationBD; //This class is application scoped

    How to access applicationBD in this layer?  

     //facescontext is null while calling this service from SOAP UI
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getContext();
    servletContext.getAttribute("applicationStartupBD");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced what you want to do is advisable, best design. Or even legal :). You can access the `ServletContext` from a chain starting with the `WebServiceContext`

1. Inject a reference to the `WebServiceContext` into your SIB

   ```
   @Resource
   WebServiceContext ctxt;
   ```
2. From the `WebServiceContext`, retrieve the `MessageContext`(which is closer to the SOAP payload processing structure of webservices than the previous context). From this, you'll get the `ServletContext`

   ```
   MessageContext msgContext = ctxt.getMessageContext();
   ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)msgContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
   IApplication app = (IApplication)  servletContext.getAttribute("applicationStartupBD"); //You can do whatever you please at this point
   ```

Is this a recommended approach? No. You have the dependency switched. The webapp should be dependent on the webservice and not the other way around. IMO, the webapp is more subject to change and is the first layer in the stack. I'll recommend you stick to a loose coupling between both layers